# What exactly is wrong here?

Tags: batch-file

I'm a new batch programmer and I'm trying to use the `if` command with the `goto`, I have some code above that I *borrowed* to define the day then I want to use that to run specific commands, different for each day, I was testing it but it ended up running all of them one after the other, what am I doing wrong here?

```bat
if %dow% EQU 0 goto Sunday
if %dow% EQU 1 goto Monday
if %dow% EQU 2 goto Tuesday
if %dow% EQU 3 goto Wednesday
if %dow% EQU 4 goto Thursday
if %dow% EQU 5 or 6 goto Friday or Saturday

timeout 100
 

:Sunday
Echo sunday

Timeout 100
Exit
:Monday
Echo Monday

Timeout 100
Exit
:Tuesday
Echo Tuesday

Timeout 100
Exit
:Wednesday
Echo Wednesday 

Timeout 100
Exit
:Thursday
Echo Thursday

Timeout 100
Exit
:Friday or Saturday
Echo Weekend

Timeout 100
Exit
```

Comment: if you're new then seriously just learn powershell. Avoid cmd with the nasty legacy defects

Comment: instead of all those `if`s, I would do `goto :label%dow%` and redefine the labels like `:label0 Sunday` (where the word `Sunday` is just ignored and serves just for human readability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if %dow% EQU 5 or 6 goto Friday or Saturday
```

This is wrong. Run `if /?` and you'll see that the syntax is

```
IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command
```

So obviously there's no "or" there. Besides `goto Friday or Saturday` makes zero sense! How can you go to both positions? Or do you want to random position? That makes even less sense.

OK I reread the code and it turns out you're defining the label as `:Friday or Saturday`. It doesn't work like that. A label can't have spaces in it:

> ```
>   label   A predefined label in the batch program.
>           Each label must be defined on a line by itself, beginning with
>           a colon and ending with either a space, a colon or a CR/LF.
> ```
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html

You'll need separate comparisons for that:

```
if %dow% EQU 5 goto Friday_or_Saturday
if %dow% EQU 6 goto Friday_or_Saturday

:Friday_or_Saturday
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch functions have to end with `goto :eof` or `exit /b`, there is no automatic detection for the end of a `function`

```
if %dow% EQU 0 goto Sunday
if %dow% EQU 1 goto Monday
...
exit /b
 

:Sunday
Echo sunday
exit /b

:Monday
echo Monday
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, i used both of your suggestions and it worked, here is the new code and thanks agin for your help!

```
if %downum% EQU 0 goto Sunday
if %downum% EQU 1 goto Monday
if %downum% EQU 2 goto Tuesday
if %downum% EQU 3 goto Wednesday
if %downum% EQU 4 goto Thursday
if %downum% GEQ 5 goto Weekend

timeout 100
 

:Sunday
Echo sunday

Timeout 100
Exit
:Monday
Echo Monday

Timeout 100
exit /b
:Tuesday
Echo Tuesday

Timeout 100
exit /b
:Wednesday
Echo Wednesday 

Timeout 100
exit /b
:Thursday
Echo Thursday

Timeout 100
exit /b
:Friday or Saturday
Echo Weekend

Timeout 100
exit /b
```